# How should i write the yaml file for use in ansible variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I started to deploying an ansible server, and i was trying to create 5 users in the client hosts, through a playbook (add5userslist.yaml), with a loop that uses variables in a list from another file (userslist.yaml), but isnt working.

And...[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7TJb.png) is what ansible retrieves when i try to use this playbook with that list:

Seems like the problem is the list used in fact ansible doesnt even sees that as a list, but well im new in ansible and dont know what should that file have.

the playbook code:

```
- hosts: GrupoPrincipal

  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: /etc/ansible/playbooks/userslist.yaml
        name: userslist
    - name: Add 5 users from a list
      ansible.builtin.user:
       name: "{{ item.name }}"
       password: "{{'abc123.' | password_hash('sha512')}}"
      loop: "{{ userslist }}"
```

the userlist.yaml code is only this, is the only thing that worked a little:

```
name: 'user1'
name: 'user2'
name: 'user3'
name: 'user4'
name: 'user5'
```

@Martin helped me with the problem above, but now im trying with more than 1 item type, doenst seems to work, here is how i have the new code

```
- hosts: GrupoPrincipal

  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: /etc/ansible/playbooks/userslist.yaml
        name: userslist

    - name: Add 5 users from a list and put them in groups
      ansible.builtin.user:
       name: "{{ item.names }}"
       groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
       password: "{{'abc123.' | password_hash('sha512')}}"
      loop:
      - { names: '{{ userslist.names }}', groups: '{{ userslist.groups }}' }
```

and the new list yaml:

```
names:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
  - user4
  - user5
groups:
  - users
  - users
  - users
  - users
  - users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling to your task to loop over an object who's representing your files variables but loop require a list.

You have to define your var_files like :

```yml
users:
  - user1
  - user2
```

And then in your main playbook, removing "item.name" in order to just use the item, and precise inside your varfile what variable you use :

```yml
- hosts: GrupoPrincipal

  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: /etc/ansible/playbooks/userslist.yaml
        name: userslist

    - name: Add 5 users from a list
      ansible.builtin.user:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       password: "{{'abc123.' | password_hash('sha512')}}"
      loop: "{{ userslist.users }}"
```

Comment: Thanks! @Martin it helped me a lot and now works, but now im trying to use this with more than 1 item  type in the list, adding groups to the userslist.yaml, for example, but doenst seems to work, i edited the main post with how is this now, can u help me again?